# How to get offline users by session in Laravel? It some overlooks when get offline users

Tags: php, laravel

I have system where I check user's offline status with a few things:

1. If user doesn't have a valid value in the `sessions` table
2. If user has not taken any action within the time specified by the admin
3. If manually logout

I check login-logout of users with [rappasoft/laravel-authentication-log](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-authentication-log)
I control user inactivity time with `Cache` via a middleware.
And I have a traite that I wrote in the `User` model.
Relevant code snippets in the `User` model:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use LaravelPermissionToVueJS;
    // ... and more
    use UserActivity; // this is my trait

    // other attributes, methods ...
    
    public function sessions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Session::class);
    }

    public function authentications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(AuthenticationLog::class, 'authenticatable')->latest('login_at');
    }

    public function lastLoginAt()
    {
        return optional($this->authentications()->first())->login_at;
    }

    public function lastLogoutAt()
    {
        return optional($this->authentications()->first())->logout_at ?? optional($this->authentications()->skip(1)->first())->logout_at;
    }

    // other relation methods ...
}
```

My `UserActivity` trait:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Enums\User\UserType;
use App\Models\General\SerializedSetting;

/**
 * User Activity Methods
 */
trait UserActivity
{
    /**
     * Get online users
     */
    public static function getOnlineUsers()
    {
        // get user online time
        $serializedSetting = SerializedSetting::where('setting', 'user_online_time')->first();
        $seconds = intval($serializedSetting->value['seconds']);

        return self::where('user_type', strval(UserType::employee))
            ->where('last_seen', '>=', now()->subSeconds($seconds))
            ->get();
    }

    /**
     * Get offline users
     */
    public static function getOfflineUsers()
    {
        // get user online time
        $serializedSetting = SerializedSetting::where('setting', 'user_online_time')->first();
        $seconds = intval($serializedSetting->value['seconds']);

        $employees = self::where('user_type', strval(UserType::employee))->get();
        $onlineEmployees = self::getOnlineUsers();
        $logoutEmployees = collect([]);

        foreach ($onlineEmployees as $onlineEmployee) {
            if (
                !is_null($onlineEmployee->lastLogoutAt()) &&
                $onlineEmployee->lastLogoutAt()->getTimestamp() >= now()->subSeconds($seconds)->getTimestamp()
            ) {
                $logoutEmployees->push($onlineEmployee);
            }
        }

        return $employees->diff($onlineEmployees->diff($logoutEmployees));
    }
}
```

Both methods in Trait work perfectly. **BUT** when a session ends in the `UserActivity` **middleware**, that user is missed. Here is middleware:

```php
class UserActivity
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {

            /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
            $user = auth()->user();

            $condition = (
                $user->user_type == strval(UserType::employee) &&
                !Cache::has('locked-for-user-' . $user->id) &&
                !Cache::has('user-id-' . $user->id . '-is-online') &&
                url()->previous() != route('login')
            );

            // only employees
            if ($condition) {
                $user->tokens()->delete();
                SessionHelper::flushCreatedSession($user->sessions->first());
                auth()->guard('web')->logout();
            }

            // seconds
            $serializedSetting = SerializedSetting::where('setting', 'user_online_time')->first();
            $seconds = intval($serializedSetting->value['seconds']);

            // keep online for until the specified time
            $expiresAt = now()->addSeconds($seconds);

            Cache::put('user-id-' . $user->id . '-is-online', true, $expiresAt);
            Cache::put('locked-for-user-' . $user->id, true, now()->addSeconds(10));

            // update last seen
            $user->update([
                'last_seen' => now(),
            ]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The `flushCreatedSession()` method here does this:

```php
if (!$userSession->isExpired()) {
    $userSession->last_activity += (
        (
            Carbon::now()
                ->subMinutes(config('session.lifetime'))
                ->getTimestamp()
        ) - (
            $userSession->last_activity
        )
    );
    $userSession->save();
}
```

My session driver is **database** and also here `Session` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class Session extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'last_activity',
        'registered_user_id',
        'registered_user_fullname',
        'registered_user_created_date',
        'city',
        'state',
        'country',
        'country_code',
        'continent',
        'continent_code',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'expires_at',
    ];

    public function isExpired()
    {
        return (
            $this->last_activity < (
                Carbon::now()
                    ->subMinutes(config('session.lifetime'))
                    ->getTimestamp()
            )
        );
    }

    public function getExpiresAtAttribute()
    {
        return (
            Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->last_activity)
                ->addMinutes(config('session.lifetime'))
                ->toDateTimeString()
        );
    }
}
```

Why can't I get that user as offline users after the session of the inactive users is terminated by the middleware. Got a tip?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding it fully, but I do see a flaw in `if ($condition) { ... }` in that you still run the code after this block so the user (which you retrieve before potentially logging them out) is still marked as online. Maybe try a `return next($request);` after the line `auth()->guard('web')->logout();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding the code fully, but I do see a flaw in block

```
if ($condition) {
    $user->tokens()->delete();
    SessionHelper::flushCreatedSession($user->sessions->first());
    auth()->guard('web')->logout();
}
```

You still run the code after this block so the user (which you retrieve before potentially logging them out) is still marked as online.

You can add a `return next($request);` at the end of this block to stop execution of the middleware at that point e.g.:

```
class UserActivity
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {

            /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
            $user = auth()->user();

            $condition = (
                $user->user_type == strval(UserType::employee) &&
                !Cache::has('locked-for-user-' . $user->id) &&
                !Cache::has('user-id-' . $user->id . '-is-online') &&
                url()->previous() != route('login')
            );

            // only employees
            if ($condition) {
                $user->tokens()->delete();
                SessionHelper::flushCreatedSession($user->sessions->first());
                auth()->guard('web')->logout();
                // ---- Here ----
                return $next($request);
            }

            // seconds
            $serializedSetting = SerializedSetting::where('setting', 'user_online_time')->first();
            $seconds = intval($serializedSetting->value['seconds']);

            // keep online for until the specified time
            $expiresAt = now()->addSeconds($seconds);

            Cache::put('user-id-' . $user->id . '-is-online', true, $expiresAt);
            Cache::put('locked-for-user-' . $user->id, true, now()->addSeconds(10));

            // update last seen
            $user->update([
                'last_seen' => now(),
            ]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```